# Using NetworkImageView in fragments - androidstudio

Tags: java, android, fragment, android-volley

Im trying to download images in fragment using volley libs. but I cannot fix error:

```html
public static class ViewFragment extends Fragment {

        ImageLoader mImageLoader;
        NetworkImageView mNetworkImageView;
        private static String IMAGE_URL =
                "http://meteo.profi-net.sk/webcams/BIELAPUT-l.jpg";

        public ViewFragment() {
            // Required empty public constructor
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Get the NetworkImageView that will display the image.
            mNetworkImageView = (NetworkImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.networkImageView);

            // Get the ImageLoader through your singleton class.
            mImageLoader = VolleySingleton.getInstance(this).getImageLoader();  //!!!!!! HERE IS THE ERROR

            // Set the URL of the image that should be loaded into this view, and
            // specify the ImageLoader that will be used to make the request.
            mNetworkImageView.setImageUrl(IMAGE_URL, mImageLoader);

        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_camera_view, container, false);
        }


    }
```

getInstance(this) is marked as mistake but I dont know how to change it. Its wokrs if I write exactly same code in some activity.

Can someone explain me how to use NetworkImageView in fragments please?

Comment: Is it necessary to pass Context to getInstance? Could you remove "this"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getInstance needs a Context as argument, Fragment is not but Activity is.
Fragment could access its holding activity by calling getActivity method. You should check every time before that call that fragment is still attached to its activity or you will get crashes

So you could do that :

```
if(isAdded())
{
            .......... your code ..............
            // Get the ImageLoader through your singleton class.
            mImageLoader = VolleySingleton.getInstance(getActivity()).getImageLoader();
                .......... your code ..............
}
```